# Scrolling the ListView sets colors to all the buttons that do not satisfy the conditions in getview method of SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have implemented a `ListView` using `SimpleAdapter` in Android. I have set certain conditions in the `getView` method of the `SimpleAdapter`.

According to the satisfied conditions the `Buttons` present in each row of the ListView will be turned to Red, Green, Yellow or Orange.

The problem I am encountering is that when I scroll the ListView up and down continously I can see that some Buttons that don't satisfy the conditions are also changing the colors and at the end all the Buttons have the above mentioned color.

Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong.My codes are as below:

```
     BaseAdapter waiter_adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), list_details_from_db,
                    R.layout.waiter_screen_details/* waiter_order_details */,
                    new String[] { "table_no", "order_id" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.tv_table_no, R.id.order_id }) {

                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*final*/ View v = super.getView(position, convertView,
                            parent);
                    // Log.i("key values sub id in get view ",
                    // ""+key_names);

                    final TextView order_id = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.order_id);
                    Log.i("Order id check from getview ", order_id
                            .getText().toString());
                    Button bt_waiter_id = (Button) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.bt_waiter_id);
                    Button placed_id = (Button) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.placed_id);
                    Button confirmed = (Button) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.confirmed);
                    Button prepared = (Button) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.prepared);
                    prepared.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String o_id = order_id.getText().toString();
                            Intent prep_list = new Intent(
                                    Waiter_Order_List_ctivity.this,
                                    Prep_List_activity.class);

                            prep_list.putExtra("Order_Id", o_id
                            /* order_id_to_intent */);
                            Log.i("Order id sent to Prep list", o_id /* order_id_to_intent */);

                            startActivity(prep_list);
                        }
                    });
                    confirmed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                    final String order_id_str = order_id.getText()
                            .toString();

                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = db
                            .get_order_course_list(order_id_str);
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> c = db
                            .get_item_status(order_id_str);

                    // if(item_status_from_db.get(index))
                    Log.i("item status retrievd from db", "" + c);
                    Log.i("database retrieved values from order course list",
                            "" + data);
                    Log.i("data size", "" + data.size());
                    try {
                        placed_id.setText(data.get(0).get("ist"));
                        confirmed.setText(data.get(0).get("confirm_ist"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        count = 0;
                        count_confirmed = 0;
                        count_processed = 0;
                        if (list_details_from_db.get(position)
                                .get("status")
                                .compareToIgnoreCase("Initial") == 0) {
                            bt_waiter_id.setBackground(getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(
                                            R.drawable.waitr_ordr_red_btn));
                            bt_waiter_id.setText("Waiter Id:"
                                    + "\n"
                                    + list_details_from_db.get(position)
                                            .get("initial_status"));

                        } else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                                String status_str = data.get(i).get(
                                        "status1");
                                if (status_str
                                        .compareToIgnoreCase("Placed") == 0) {
                                    count++;
                                }
                                if (status_str
                                        .compareToIgnoreCase("Confirmed") == 0) {
                                    count_confirmed++;
                                }
                                if (status_str
                                        .compareToIgnoreCase("Processed") == 0) {
                                    count_processed++;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        if (count > 0) {
                            placed_id
                                    .setBackground(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.waitr_ordr_yellow_btn));
                        }
                        if (count_confirmed > 0) {
                            confirmed
                                    .setBackground(getResources()
                                            .getDrawable(
                                                    R.drawable.waitr_ordr_orange_btn));
                            /*
                             * confirmed
                             * .setOnClickListener(Waiter_Order_List_ctivity
                             * .this);
                             */
                        }
                        if (count_processed > 0) {
                            prepared.setBackground(getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(
                                            R.drawable.waitr_ordr_green_btn));
                            /*
                             * prepared.setOnClickListener(
                             * Waiter_Order_List_ctivity.this);
                             */
                        }
                        if (c.size() > 0) {
                            prepared.setBackground(getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(
                                            R.drawable.waitr_ordr_green_btn));
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    placed_id
                            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Intent intTableItm = new Intent(
                                            Waiter_Order_List_ctivity.this,
                                            Waiter_Confirm.class);
                                    intTableItm.putExtra("Order_Id",
                                            order_id_str);
                                    startActivity(intTableItm);
                                }
                            });
                    return v;
                }

            };
            w_order_list.setAdapter(waiter_adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the reusage of the Listitems. If you change the Background in the if condition:

```
 if (list_details_from_db.get(position)
```

You have to set it to the default background in the else condition.

//edit

```
 @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*final*/ View v = super.getView(position, convertView,
                        parent);
                // Log.i("key values sub id in get view ",
                // ""+key_names);

                final TextView order_id = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.order_id);
                Log.i("Order id check from getview ", order_id
                        .getText().toString());
                Button bt_waiter_id = (Button) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.bt_waiter_id);
                Button placed_id = (Button) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.placed_id);
                Button confirmed = (Button) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.confirmed);
                Button prepared = (Button) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.prepared);



                placed_id.setText("Your standard value");
                confirmed.setText("Your standard value");
                placed_id.setBackground(getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(
                                                R.drawable.your_standard_drawable));
                confirmed.setBackground(getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(
                                                R.drawable.your_standard_drawable));
                prepared.setBackground(getResources()
                                .getDrawable(
                                        R.drawable.your_standard_drawable));
                bt_waiter_id.setBackground(getResources()
                                .getDrawable(
                                        R.drawable.your_standard_drawable));
                bt_waiter_id.setText("your standard value");

                //
                //[...] Rest of your code

            }
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Anyother suggestion

Comment: The "problem" wich you are desribe depends definitly on the normal behaviour of a ListView. The adapter will call getView as many times as List Items are VISIBLE. If you scroll, any new item will be build out of a control wich is not visible any more (scrolled away). If you change something on a ListItem, it will be appear later in an other Item if you don't set the Changes back

Comment: Can you just explain me what changes i have to make in my code?

Comment: You have several parts in your code wich changes some Background ressources of parts from a List item. But a Listview will reuse former created Items when you Scroll the List (in order to speed up the  List). The easiest way to avoid the effekts ist to set every drawable which you might change to his default value in top of the getView() function I will edit my Post below to clarify